# How to get Wikia links into a listview in Android, maybe MediaWiki API would help but I am not sure on where to go with this

Tags: java, android, listview, mediawiki, listactivity

I am creating an Android app based on The Legend of Zelda, I wanted to link to the Wikia pages for the Zelda video games located at: http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Games ; I was wondering if there was a way to get the page names for each game and import them to a listview in my Android app.  The way that I am currently doing this is directly coding the names of the games into the app itself, but if I could do it so it would pull the names for me then I wouldn't have to update every time that a new game comes out, and it would save on hard coding all of these names in there.  The code I have so far is as follows:

```
    package com.lvlup.kikurself.zeldatest;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    public class zeldaGames extends ListActivity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "The Legend of Zelda", "Zelda II: The
         Adventure of Link", "The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time",};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        final ListView zeldaList = getListView();

        zeldaList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long thisID)
      {
         Object o = (zeldaList.getItemAtPosition(position));
         String gameName_temp = (o.toString());

         Intent newIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), gameDisp.class);
         newIntent.putExtra("tempG", gameName_temp);
         startActivity(newIntent);

    }
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read this.

I have been looking at the MediaWiki API and have found this:

```
 http://zelda.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Games&cmlimit=500
```

This will list the games but it is in xml format I am still confused as to how i would get the game titles to enter into my list.  Please help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for the API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) and at [the API help](http://zelda.wikia.com/api.php)? Specifically, it seems you want the `categorymembers` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best bet would be to use `HTML Parser` and parse the content you need to display.

Here is Java implementation of `HTML Parser`

http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

another one

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

You need to look for `<div class="category-gallery">` particular `DIV` which will be constant for every game page.

Inside that `DIV`, every game is listed inside another `DIV`

```
<div class="category-gallery-item category-gallery-item-image">
```

which have content like Name, URL, Image, etc...

```
<a title="The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword" href="/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Skyward_Sword">
<img alt="The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb51062/zelda/images/thumb/b/b9/Characters_%28Skyward_Sword%29.png/130px-77%2C1066%2C0%2C874-Characters_%28Skyward_Sword%29.png">
<span class="details">The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword</span>
</a>
```

from here you can parse the stuff you need. This also works fast enough, so no need to worry about performance.